# Drawing a Chart for non-numerical variables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I have a issue with chart drawing in my Windows form application project.

I want to draw a chart like this:
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-12/84930837744513480976.jpg

the words in axis X and axis Y is related and that letters in colorful rectangles are each relation's value. I want a chart exactly like this.
anyone can help me to draw something like that?
I''l be thankful.

Regards.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about it doesn't work? Your question is far too broad as it is.

Comment: Pen and a pad of paper?

Comment: You can do this in two ways: Either draw the things using the Graphics methods,: DrawLine, DrawRectangle, FillRectangle and DrawString. - Or you can use the Chart control. Her you could do it in code, but I suggest to use the VS designer.. Not knowing what you really want to do I can't advise..but for quick results and full control I guess I would draw the thing myself..

Comment: I draw lots of charts in my project working with chart class.
but I couldn't find match type for this kind of chart.
if you are familiar with fuzzy systems, this chart shows a simple 2d knowledge base.
I hope you guys save my ass in this project! submission time is 2 days later.

Comment: I have updated the code a little..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class `AreaChart` which draws a chart like the one you showed.

Here is what it looks like, with the built-in values:

[image: AreaChart]

Add the class to your project and compile. It'll show up in the toolbox and you can place it on your form.  (Do a Backup of your project before you do that!)

You can set many values in the designer or in code, including the dimensions, `BackColor, Font,  and Labels`.. Set the Colors and Texts in code using the methods provided!

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

class AreaChart : Panel
{
     [Category("Appearance"), Description("Padding around the ChartArea")]
    public Padding ChartPadding { get; set; }
     [Category("Appearance"), 
              Description("Axixs Origin offsets from Bottom Left of the Chart")]
    public Point AxisOriginOffset { get; set; }
     [Category("Appearance"),Description("Number of Rows")]
    public int RowNum { get; set; }
     [Category("Appearance"), Description("Number of Columns")]
    public int ColNum { get; set; }

     [Category("Appearance"), Description("Labeltexts for Y-Axis")]
    public string[] labelsY { get; set; }
     [Category("Appearance"), Description("Labeltexts for X-Axis")]
    public string[] labelsX { get; set; }

    Color[][] colors { get; set; }
    string[][] texts { get; set; }

    Rectangle chartArea = Rectangle.Empty;
    Point axisOrigin = Point.Empty


    public void Init()
    {
        chartArea = new Rectangle(ChartPadding.Left, ChartPadding.Top,
                    this.Width - ChartPadding.Left - ChartPadding.Right, 
                    this.Height - ChartPadding.Top - ChartPadding.Bottom);

        axisOrigin = new Point(AxisOriginOffset.X, this.Height - AxisOriginOffset.Y);

        colors = new Color[RowNum][];
        for (int r = 0; r < RowNum; r++) colors[r] = new Color[ColNum];
        texts = new string[RowNum][];
        for (int r = 0; r < RowNum; r++) texts[r] = new string[ColNum];
        labelsX = new string[ColNum];  //*
        labelsY = new string[RowNum];  //*
    }


    public AreaChart()
    {
        ChartPadding = new Padding(80, 40, 40, 40);
        AxisOriginOffset = new Point(60, 20);
        RowNum = 3;
        ColNum = 2;
        BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;

        Init();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DesignMode) Init();      // make the designer show the current
        if (this.DesignMode) InitDemo();  // ...sizes, colors and texts

        int x = chartArea.X;
        int y = chartArea.Y;
        SizeF tSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("XX", this.Font, 9999);
        int th = (int)tSize.Height / 2;
        int tw = (int)tSize.Width / 2;
        int h = chartArea.Height / RowNum;
        int w = chartArea.Width / ColNum; e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, axisOrigin, 
                            new Point(axisOrigin.X, chartArea.Top));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, axisOrigin, 
                            new Point( chartArea.Right, axisOrigin.Y));

        for (int r = 0; r < RowNum; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < ColNum; c++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colors[r][c]), 
                  x + c * w, y + r * h, w, h);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x + c * w, y + r * h, w, h);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[r][c], this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
                  x + c * w  + w / 2 - tw, y + r * h + h / 2 - th);

            }
        for (int r = 0; r < RowNum; r++)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(labelsY[r], this.Font, Brushes.Black, 
              AxisOriginOffset.X - tw * 2, y + r * h + h / 2 - th);  //*

        for (int c = 0; c < ColNum; c++)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(labelsX[c], this.Font, Brushes.Black,
                x + c * w + w / 2 - tw, axisOrigin.Y );             //*

        base.OnPaint(e);;
    }

    public void setColor (int row, int col, Color color)
    {
        try
        {
            colors[row][col] = color;
        } catch { throw new Exception("setColor : array index out of bounds!"); }
    }

    public void setText(int row, int col, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            texts[row][col] = text;
        } catch { throw new Exception("setText: array index out of bounds!"); }
    }

    public void setLabelX(int col, string text)      //*
    {
        try
        {
            labelsX[col] = text;
        } catch { throw new Exception("array index out of bounds!"); }
    }

    public void setLabelY(int row, string text)      //*
    {
        try
        {
            labelsY[row] = text;
        } catch { throw new Exception("array index out of bounds!"); }
    }

    public void InitDemo()
    {
        setColor(0, 0, Color.Plum);
        setColor(1, 0, Color.GreenYellow);
        setColor(2, 0, Color.Gold);
        setColor(0, 1, Color.LightSkyBlue);
        setColor(1, 1, Color.NavajoWhite);
        setColor(2, 1, Color.Pink);

        setText(0, 0, "AA");
        setText(1, 0, "BA");
        setText(2, 0, "CA");
        setText(0, 1, "AB");
        setText(1, 1, "BB");
        setText(2, 1, "BC");

        setLabelY(0, "A");     //*
        setLabelY(1, "B");     //*
        setLabelY(2, "C");     //*

        setLabelX(0, "A");     //*
        setLabelX(1, "B");     //*
    }


}
```

After your Form's `Initializecomponent()` you should call

```
areaChart1.Init();
areaChart1.InitDemo();
```

to display the demo chart I show. To change it use calls like these:

```
areaChart1.ColNum = 3;
areaChart1.Init();
areaChart1.InitDemo();
areaChart1.setColor(0, 2, Color.Yellow);
areaChart1.setLabelY(2, "ZZ");
//..
```

Comment: Thanks! it's very useful, but have some problems.
1- How can I manage the position and size of the chart on Group Box.
2- I want another label set in axis X of chart.
my time running low please help me. strongly waiting for your feedback. 
Regards.

Comment: 1 - ?? If you have placed the chart in a groupbox you can move it around & resize itwith the mouse? no? - 2- you are right, I had forgotten them. See the (__//*__) updated answer!

Comment: no I put chart in group box and it appear in very small size (even when my group box is large). I try to change its size but only background of chart changes and chart's size remain the same.
i use this:
AreaChart a1=new AreaChart();
.
.
a1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 250);

Comment: I know, this is a display issue in the designer; not sure when I have time to fix it.- It is only in th designer, though. at runtime it will fill its area!

Comment: @Ali Crash: Found a fix: If you add the two first lines of the OnPaint code, the chart will show up correctly in the desgner!

Comment: I am afraid that's not makes a difference. 
http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-12/38813579464418678330.jpg
thank you anyway, but problem is still remains.

Comment: Hm, that's strange, it works here. I'm talking about the `if (this.DesignMode) Init();if (this.DesignMode) InitDemo();`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but if you want EXACTLY that chart, does that mean you don't need the values to be dynamic? If so, wouldn't the simplest solution be to save it as an image and display the image in your application where you need it. Obviously this won't work if you need the values or colors to be dynamic.

Comment: No no! they are dynamic!!!
all I need is a chart format like that! 
I thought it's a simple task for C# dudes!